# VB 6 with Crystal report 11 in Windows 7

Tags: vb6, windows-7-x64, crystal-reports-xi

I have  an existing VB 6 application created and compiled in Windows XP. It uses Crystal report 8. The data comes from DB2 database. Recently the application is shifted to Windows 7 platform. Version 11 of crystal report is isntalled in that machine. The compilation was successfull but during runtime while opening up the crystal report is throwing error "error 20599 ; Cannot open SQL Server".
Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same code is working in XP. But not so in Windows 7 although the same userid and password is being used.

Answer (score 2):

use this command this works for me

.Connect = "DSN=" & ODBCcon name & ";UID=" & UID & ";PWD=" & PWD & ";DSQ=Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002" '& lstrDBName

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
".Connect = "Driver={Mysql ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost;port=3306; database=db; user=root; password=; option=3;"
```